# vue lazyload, do something after image error

Tags: vue.js, lazy-loading

I want let data of "imageError" be true if lazyload is error

HTML

```
<div v-lazy:background-image="imgObj"></div>
```

JS

```
data() {
  imageError: false
},

comuted: {
  imgObj() {
    return {
      src: srcImage,
      error: errImage,
      loading: loadingImage,
      adapter: {
          loading (listender, Init) {
              console.log('loading')
          },
          error (listender, Init) {
            // if lazyload image error return true
            this.imageError = true
            console.log('error')
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

src/error/loading image is work, but adapter doesn't work, is there anyelse way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The `adapter` property is reserved for the `plugin` option, it's not available as a `directive` options.

You should instead use the `$LazyLoad` object that is bound to your component instance and hook into the listener for `error`:

```
this.$Lazyload.$on('error', function (errors) {
  console.log(errors)
})
```